# list overwirite all elements

Tags: java, arrays, list

i have list array of type Car , but in for loop i set to it some variable strings

but after finished looping i found the last element of list is overwrite all previous elements

```
    Car testset = new Car();


private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size,
        List<Integer> teachers, List<String> state){
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            list.add(testset.add(getRandomColor(teachers.get(i)),
                    getRandomYear(state.get(i))
                    ));
```

car class :

```
    private String teachers;
private String state;

public Car add(String teachers,String state) {

    this.teachers=teachers;
    this.state=state;

    return Car.this;
}
```

Comment: So you're modifying and adding the same `Car` object every time...

Comment: I want to add car and new car and new car and so on , how can i fix this ?

Comment: Look into this keyword: `new`. Then read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add Car objects in the list. Your for loop should instantiate a new Car object each time.

```
Car testset = null;

try {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  testset = new Car();

  list.add(testset.add(getRandomColor(teachers.get(i)), getRandomYear(state.get(i))));

  // Additional code goes here.

 } catch (Exception ex) {
   // Exception handling
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems that your question is incomplete.
Secondly, to fix up your code, just add the

```
Car car = new Car();// testset->car
```

inside the `populateRandomCars` method.

Then it will create and add a new Car.

Comment: do you mean inside loop ? :)